# Ramsey type theorem for polygons on lattices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring, polygons, integer-lattices, ramsey-theory

It's not difficult to show that given a 2-coloring of the lattice $L:=\{1,2,3\} \times \{1,\dots,9\} \subseteq \mathbb Z^2$ we find a monochromatic rectangle in $L$. Generalizing, for any $r$-coloring on $\mathbb Z^2$ can we always find a lattice $L \subseteq \mathbb Z^2$ containing a given monochromatic polygon? How large is a minimal $L$?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a "given monochromatic polygon"? Does it mean a series of $k$ links such that they are all of one color and they form a closed chain (so that re rectangle might be $1\leftarrow 8 \leftarrow 3 \leftarrow 7 \leftarrow 1$ ? Are self-intersections allowed?

Comment: Can you show your proof for the rectangle case?

Comment: Yes, too unspecific, I admit. Let's restrict to convex polygons, allow scaling the original polygon if we preserve symmetries. I.e. {(1,1), (3,1),(2,3)} counts as triangle just as {(1,1),(5,1),(3,2)} does. Rotations allowed.
@i9Fn The proof for the rectangle case uses the pigeon hole principle twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large enough lattice definitely always exists, but how large exactly depends on the specifics of the problem.

Either way, it's a good idea to reduce the 'monochromatic polygon' problem to a 'monochromatic sublattice' problem as follows: given vertices $(x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_k, y_k)$ of a canonical instance of this polygon, define the sublattice $S$ to be $S := \{x_1, \dots, x_k\} \times \{y_1, \dots, y_k\}$. Example: $$P = \begin{Bmatrix}  & (1,2) & (1,3) \\ (2,1) & & (2,3) \\ & (3,2) \end{Bmatrix}\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad S = \begin{Bmatrix} (1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) \\ (2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) \\ (3,1) & (3,2) & (3,3) \end{Bmatrix}$$ If we find a monochromatic copy of $S$, then we find a monochromatic copy of $P$.

What we mean by a "copy of $S$" depends on what "copy of $P$" meant. In the case of the polygon $P$ given above, is any polygon with vertices $\{(x_1, y_2), (x_1, y_3), (x_2, y_1), (x_2, y_3), (x_3, y_2)\}$ a copy of $P$? Or is it important that $|x_1 - x_2| = |x_2 - x_3|$, and that $|y_1 - y_2| = |y_2 - y_3|$? Should we also ask that $|x_1 - x_2| = |y_1 - y_2|$?

---

The first version is the most forgiving, and in this case, any sublattice with the same number of rows and columns as $S$ should be considered a "copy of $S$".

We can solve this in basically the exact same way as the rectangle problem. Say we're looking for a copy of a $k \times \ell$ lattice $S$. Then just take the large lattice $L$ to be $kr \times \ell r\binom{kr}{r}$. This has a monochromatic copy of $S$ in  it, since:

- In each column, at least $k$ points must receive the same color.
- There are $r\binom{kr}{r}$ ways to say which $k$ points and which color that is, and $\ell$ times as many columns, so at least $\ell$ columns have the same $k$ points repeated in the same color.
- This is a monochromatic copy of $S$.

I'm being slightly sloppy with the pigeonhole here, and we're also giving away a lot with the polygon to sublattice reduction. But the result is still polynomial in $k$ and $\ell$ for a fixed $r$, which is pretty good.

---

The least permissive version of the sublattice problem (which should find you copies of a polygon in any sense of the word "copy") is when we're looking for a $k \times \ell$ sublattice in which the distances between any two adjacent rows or columns are all equal. For the purposes of symmetry, let's make this a $t \times t$ sublattice, where $t = \max\{k,\ell\}$.

This can be reduced to the [Hales–Jewett theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hales%E2%80%93Jewett_theorem) (again, in much the same way that the monochromatic square problem can be reduced to Hales–Jewett). Take the $n$-dimensional grid $\{1,2,\dots,t^2\}^n$ and "flatten it out" into a lattice recursively: think of this grid as $t^2$ copies of the $n-1$-dimensional grid $\{1,2,\dots, t^2\}^{n-1}$ (parametrized by the first coordinate) and arrange their flattened-out versions in a $t \times t$ square. For example, for $t=2$ and $n=3$, we get
$$
\begin{matrix}
  111 & 112 & 121 & 122 & 211 & 212 & 221 & 222 \\
  113 & 114 & 123 & 124 & 213 & 214 & 223 & 224 \\
  131 & 132 & 141 & 142 & 231 & 232 & 241 & 242 \\
  133 & 134 & 143 & 144 & 233 & 234 & 243 & 244 \\
  311 & 312 & 321 & 322 & 411 & 412 & 421 & 422 \\
  313 & 314 & 323 & 324 & 413 & 414 & 423 & 424 \\
  331 & 332 & 341 & 342 & 431 & 432 & 441 & 442 \\
  333 & 334 & 343 & 344 & 433 & 434 & 443 & 444
\end{matrix}
$$
A combinatorial line in the $n$-dimensional grid will translate to a $t\times t$ sublattice of this lattice. So all we need is to choose $n$ to be at least the Hales–Jewett number $\operatorname{HJ}(r,t^2)$ and then we can find a $t\times t$ sublattice inside any $r$-coloring of the $t^n \times t^n$ lattice.

This is a very large upper bound, but necessarily so, given that this version of the polygon problem can have finding arbitrarily long monochromatic arithmetic progressions as a subtask.

Comment: Thank your for fixing my clumsy definition of what it means to be a copy of a polygon. The recursive flattening technique is intriguing, although the bound becomes enormous. In the more restrictive copy type, do you think one might avoid the transition to sublattices in order to get better bounds for the monochromatic polygon?

Comment: For some monochromatic polygons, probably; I don't think you can avoid it in general. (The monochromatic square problem, for instance, has lower bounds in terms of van der Waerden numbers - the same as where the best lower bounds on Hales-Jewett come from.)